# Joomla - Is it possible to hide pages?

Tags: php, joomla

We have inherited a Joomla website to manage - a template has been setup to link through to display partner icons - basically each partner page is connected to display the logo.

My question is whether its possible to hide the sub pages so for example partners/somebusiness so they aren't visible via url but do still connect to propvide logo and so they can be activated in future?  Or more simply - can you hide a page in joomla!?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it by unpublishing the article.

You can do that by clicking the published check next to the article name, or actually going into the article and setting it to 'unpublished'.